# Calling Switch inside onclicklistener

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a basic game, and I want to play a switch command in a onClickListener, inside if. I can't get the program to repeat the task that I want it to, which is to change colors(Between black and white) when clicked on the button.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    final View vColor = (View) findViewById (R.id.vColor);
    Button bwhite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bWhite);
    Button bblack = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bBlack);

    final Random colorBW = new Random();
    final int random = colorBW.nextInt(2);
    switch(random){
    case 0: 
        vColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);         
        break;
    case 1:
        vColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        break;
        };       

    bblack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // 0 = BLACK
        // 1 = WHITE
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (random == 0){
                    THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL MY SWITCH(RANDOM)  
            }else if (random == 1){
                Intent startGame = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.random.shot.tapthecolor.MenuScreen.class);
                startActivity(startGame);
            }
        }
    });
    bwhite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (random == 1){
                    doMySwitch(); 
            }else if (random == 0){
                Intent startGame = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.random.shot.tapthecolor.MenuScreen.class);
                startActivity(startGame);
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: check your `random` data.

Comment: Sry, i dont understand what u mean by that